Export latex code from modelsummary using kableExtra
I am trying to get the latex code from a table that I create with modelsummary and then edit with kableExtra. I know this used to work in the past, but the newer version of modelsummary does not seem to support anymore. I think the main issue is the switch from kableExtra to tinytable as deafault table editor by modelsummary, but I think it still should somehow work the same.
I know that the following code used to work in the past:
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

model1 <- lm(y1 ~ x, data)
model2 <- lm(y2 ~ x, data)

models <- 
list(model1, model2)

table <-
  modelsummary(models,
             output = "latex")

latex_table <- table %>%
kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "basic")

cat(latex_table)

However, I get the follwing error message when trying to pass the modelsummary object to kableExtra:
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("tinytable", package = "tinytable")’ to a data.frame

Using the recommended config_modelsummary(factory_default = "kableExtra") does not solve the problem and I still get the same error message.
Is there a way to still make this work with the newer version of modelsummary still using kableExtra instead of tinytable?

Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

It should be output = "kableExtra"

Please read the warning message printed every time the latest version (2.1.1) of modelsummary is loaded:
`modelsummary` 2.0.0 now uses `tinytable` as its default table-drawing
  backend. Learn more at: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/tinytable/

Revert to `kableExtra` for one session:

  options(modelsummary_factory_default = 'kableExtra')
  options(modelsummary_factory_latex = 'kableExtra')
  options(modelsummary_factory_html = 'kableExtra')

Silence this message forever:

  config_modelsummary(startup_message = FALSE)

